# como exportar e importar preventDefault() con javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, javascript-import, javascript-metodo

Me gustaría me ayuden, estoy realizando un formulario y lo estoy validando con javascript y el código se esta agrandando es por eso que estoy dividiendo en archivos, la pregunta es como exporto e importo un e.preventDefault(), les dejo un pedazo de código

```
FormularioRegCurso.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
//Validando codigo moodle
if (CodMoodle.value === "" || CodMoodle.value === null) {
  document.getElementById("ErrorRegistraCurso").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ErrorRegistraCurso").innerHTML =
    "Debe de Ingresar el Codigo Moodle";
  document.getElementById("CodMoodle").focus();
  setTimeout(DesapareceError, 2000);
}
```

});

Comment: ¿Cómo que importar o exportar el `e.preventDefault()`? ¿Con qué finalidad? ¿Qué planea usar de este método?

Comment: No puedes exportar esa funcionalidad, en todo caso, envía el evento como parámetro a las otras funciones donde necesites cancelarlo o, mejor aún, que esas funciones devuelvan un resultado y, con base en él, lo cancelas o no.